# bzero doesn't do what it says it does

Tags: c

I use `vscode` as my code editor, and in the header file `<strings.h>` there is a function called `bzero` and when hovering on the function `vscode` says that `bzero Set N bytes of S to 0.` But I don't think it works like that. I created an array of 11 chars which called `s` and placed inside it `Hello World`.

Then I used `bzero` to set the first 4 bytes of `s` to 0, but from the output it seems like it cleaned the whole buffer.

```c
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char s[11] = "Hello World";
    bzero(s, 4);

    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ cc main.c -o main && ./main
# empty
$
```

Comment: Where does `puts` stop printing, do you think? What makes a character array a string in C?

Comment: @Lundin Once `\0` arrives

Comment: You could try bzero(&s[5], 4) to see the difference. :)

Comment: @NoaKirel Indeed! And `\0` is value zero, so it stops at the very first character.

Comment: @Devolus It's different than what I want. Afaik `bzero` doesn't require a pointer.

Comment: @Lundin But `\0` is the end, it's determinds the EOF, no?

Comment: @NoaKirel Except you set the first 4 bytes to zero.

Comment: Of cours bzero requires a pointer, which s is.

Comment: You can also try `for(size_t i=0; i<11; i++) { printf("%c", s[i]); }` and it should print nothing/gibberish followed by `o World`.

Comment: @Lundin Ohhhh, now I get you. I thought that `set n bytes to 0` means just remove the chars lmao

Comment: There's generally nothing such as "removing data" in computers. The memory cells always sit there, we can just overwrite them with something new. In this case a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: @Lundin So the size of the array is still 11? Edit: Yeah seems like it is.

Comment: The code and behavior you present are fully consistent with `bzero()` behaving as documented.  Do be aware, however, that neither `bzero()` nor `strings.h` is included in the C language specification (as opposed to `string.h`).  They are characteristic of some variations of Unix, but you should prefer `string.h` and `memset()`.

Comment: Yeah the size of an array like this has static size and will always have that size until it goes out of scope at the `}` in the block where it was declared. `strlen` would however tell you size zero because it just looks for the null terminator.

Comment: @NoaKirel, yes. The size of the array will always stay the same. Only the content is changed.

Comment: Okay thanks yall, now I understand. And @JohnBollinger I didn't know that thanks, I only program in Unix platforms but from now on I'll use `memset` because it more portable

Comment: It interesting to see how can a simple function trick the whole system (`strlen`, `puts` and etc)

Comment: Not "trick".  It is best to view the string as part (possibly all) of the *contents* of an array, not as the array itself or necessarily its full contents, and certainly not as any pointer.  From that perspective, everything is natural and consistent.  Moreover, that better prepares you for the possibility that the contents of an array of `char` do not constitute a string at all, on account of not including a terminator character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`bzero`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html) does exactly what it says. The issue you’re facing is due to a misunderstanding of what a string is in C.

Briefly, a [*C string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling) is a zero-terminated buffer of `char`s. That is, C treats an array of `char`s as a string by considering all `char`s until it finds the first one whose value is 0.

`puts` (and `printf` etc.) uses this definition of “string”.

As a consequence, setting even just the first `char` in the array to 0 results in an empty string, regardless of what comes after.

(Note also that `bzero` is a legacy function and its use is discouraged; use [`memset`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html) instead.)

Answer (score 2):

Zero is a string-terminating character. Therefore if you set the first byte of your string to zero, `puts` will believe that the string is empty.

Answer (score 2):

`puts()` expects a pointer to a *string*. Strings in C is sequences of characters *terminated by a null-character (`'\0'`). Null-character is represented by a value zero.

Therefore, `puts()` stops at the first zero and prints an empty string.

Print the whole buffer to see the effect of `bzero()`.

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char s[11] = "Hello World";
    bzero(s, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) printf("%d ", s[i]); // print elements of the buffer
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 111 32 87 111 114 108 100
```